# Where is the callback function for read/write in at24 eeprom driver?

Tags: linux-device-driver, eeprom

I'm trying to understand how the read/write on "eeprom" device node in linux works ?
I'm using at24 (drivers/misc/eeprom/at24.c) i2c driver to access my eeprom. From userspace, I'm able to do open/read/write/close on the created device node and I can access the eeprom without any issues.
But I can't seem to find the corresponding callbacks defined in the at24 driver.
Does anyone know how this works ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It depends on the kernel version, but there will be a call to `sysfs_create_bin_file` somewhere that creates the sysfs file and registers the callbacks.  From kernel version 4.6 onwards it uses a combination of `devm_regmap_init` and `nvmem_register` instead. `nvmem_register` calls `dev_get_regmap` to get at the regmap initialized by the at24 driver.

Comment: Thanks. The "eeprom" sysfs entry is created as part of `nvmem_setup_compat`.